# How to list all schemas and tablespaces in Oracle from .dmp file without importing?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

So, the problem is that I have the .DMP file that was exported by a customer using exp or expdp.
I want to get some of the .dmp properties, as I do in SQLServer using the following command:

`RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N"C:\temp\myfile.bak";`

The original tablespace and schema are the infos I need to remap to a new file without using any graphical tool such as SQL Developer, and then, with the right property values, import this into my environment programatically.

I tried to build a StreamReader using CSharp, and reading the dump, I get a lot of info but i didn't see a pattern to get the schemas. **Is it possible to run a command like "RESTORE HEADERONLY" in Oracle?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [SQLFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-8453D1F2-FDA9-4658-B42E-9D5B75AFEED9.htm#SUTIL933) parameter of impdp. Just put your dump into DATA_PUMP_DIR on the server and use impdp:

```
impdp hr DIRECTORY=DATAP_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=expfull.dmp SQLFILE=DATAP_PUMP_DIR:expfull.sql
```

Comment: Thanks! With the .sql file I can read to obtain the properties.